# Python equivalent code for curl including elastic search queries

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, elasticsearch, python-requests

what should be the equivalent python requests code for:

```
curl -XGET "https://acd.int.com:9100/abc%2A/search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -k -u bfire:XXX -d'
{
"query": {
"query_string": {
"query": "@timestamp:[2018-06-29T06:47:40.000Z TO *]"
}
},
"size": 1000
}
'|json_pp
```

Comment: Maybe using the Requests library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer via https://curl.trillworks.com, need to test it on dev server though...

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

data = '\n{\n"query": {\n"query_string": {\n"query": "@timestamp:[2018-06-29T06:47:40.000Z TO *]"\n}\n},\n"size": 1000\n}\n|json_pp'

response = requests.post('https://acd.int.com:9100/abc%2A/search', headers=headers, data=data, verify=False, auth=('bfire', 'XXX'))
```